# jQuery ready event does not fire on every page load when placed in HEAD in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, document-ready

I'm noticing something strange when using the jQuery ready event in Rails. If the handler is added in the `<head>` section, either directly within script tags or in asset pipeline files included using `<%= javascript_include_tag ...`, it will only execute on the first page request, and not on subsequent requests. That is, explicit browser actions to load/refresh a page will execute it, but new page views triggered from clicking around on links will not.

On the other hand, if it's included in the `<body>`, it will fire every time on every page view- like you'd expect.

```
<head>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('READY in head'); // Fires on first page load only
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('READY in body'); // Fires every time
});
</script>
</body>
```

Really confused. I'm seeing it in all my Rails apps, but don't understand how Rails could effect this as jQuery is a client-side technology??

Comment: When you say `explicit browser actions to load/refresh a page will execute it` and that `new page views triggered from clicking around on links will not`, how is your page set up? does clicking a link actually load a new page, or does it grab a page and insert it into the dom?

Comment: @Toiletduck- are you asking about AJAX? No, they are standard page loads.

Comment: Rails *cannot* affect that except by failing to include the code. Have you checked from the client (browser) to see that everything's as you expect it to be?

Comment: Cause those both should work fine.

Comment: Yes I was asking if you were using an AJAX request. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with your code, unless your script is not in the head of all of your pages.

Comment: @Toiletduck- wait, I just realized what turbolinks are- think you're right about AJAX! (Sorry im new to Rails... idiot)

Comment: @Toiletduck Funny you say that the scripts should be in the head. One one of the sites I worked on, the load event for a particular page would only fire if the scripts were in the body.

Comment: @NigelNquande The script should only be in the head if you are actually loading a new page. If you are using AJAX to insert into the DOM then it will not fire a load event for each request. However you can use callbacks bound to your request. That works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [RailsApps Project](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html) :

> The Rails asset pipeline will become even more important in Rails 4.0
>   with the new Turbolinks feature. Turbolinks improves performance by
>   keeping the current page instance alive and replacing only the page
>   BODY (plus the title in the HEAD). As long as the HEAD element is
>   identical between pages, the Turbolinks mechanism can deliver its
>   “turbo” speed boost. This adds to the importance of avoiding any extra
>   script tags on specific pages.

Comment: I JUST realized what turbolinks are- clearly that's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: my pleasure, now you can get on with your rails voo-doo

Answer (score 1):

Using AJAX (or turbolinks) as you said would not actually load a new page, but insert it into the dom. Therefore the ready event would not fire. :)